# How to reshape 3 channel dataset for input to neural network

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to feed kth action dataset to a cnn. I am having difficulty with reshaping the data. I have created this array (99,75,120,160) type=uint8 ie, 99 videos belonging to a class with each video having 75 frames, 120x160 dimension for each frame.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'), 
                          input_shape=())) 
###need to reshape data in input_shape
```

should i specify a dense layer first?

here is my code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'), 
                          input_shape=(75,120,160)))
###need to reshape data in input_shape

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Reshape((8, 8, 1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1, (3,3), padding='same')))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

data = np.load(r"C:\Users\shj_k\Desktop\Project\handclapping.npy")
print (data.shape)
(x_train,x_test) = train_test_split(data)


x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.




print (x_train.shape)
print (x_test.shape)


model.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=1,
                shuffle=False,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

the variables are
x_test  (25,75,120,160) type=float32
x_train (74,75,120,160) type=float32

complete error for the one in comment is

> runfile('C:/Users/shj_k/Desktop/Project/cnn_lstm.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/shj_k/Desktop/Project') (99, 75, 120, 160) (74, 75,
>   120, 160) (25, 75, 120, 160) Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/shj_k/Desktop/Project/cnn_lstm.py', wdir='C:/Users/shj_k/Desktop/Project')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\shj_k\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 668, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\shj_k\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/shj_k/Desktop/Project/cnn_lstm.py", line 63, in
>   
>       validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\shj_k\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 952, in fit
>       batch_size=batch_size)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\shj_k\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 751, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\shj_k\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 128, in standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected
>   time_distributed_403_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with
>   shape (74, 75, 120, 160)

Thank you for reply

Comment: try specifying input_shape=(75, 120, 160)

Comment: i just did and got error return self._dims[key]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: i tried input_shape=(1,120,160,75) and in return got the error 
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_403_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (74, 75, 120, 160)

Comment: so TimeDistributed layer in Keras needs a time dimension, so for video image processing could be 75 here (the frames per second). Then, it expects images to be sent in 120,60, 3 format. So the final input_shape should be (75, 120, 160, 3). In Keras.preprocessing.image there is image.img_to_array(img) where you can convert a PIL image to a numpy array .

Comment: i tried replacing the input_shape as you said and still returned the same error

Comment: in the error, i saw validation_data=(x_test, x_test) which is a part of model.fit(), is the error related to any of that?

Comment: you are missing the third dimension (RGB) for images, take a look at my answer on how to create that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

The TimeDistributed layer in Keras needs a time dimension, so for video image processing this could be 75 here (the frames).

It also expects images to be sent in shape (120, 60, 3). So the TimeDistributed layer input_shape should be (75, 120, 160, 3). 3 stands for the RGB channels. If you have greyscale images, 1 as the last dimension should work.

The input_shape always ignores the "row" dimension of your examples, in your case 99.

To check the output shapes created by each layer of the model, put `model.summary()` after compiling it.

See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed

You can convert images into numpy arrays with shape (X, Y, 3) using Keras.preprocessing.image.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

# loads RGB image as PIL.Image.Image type
img = image.load_img(img_file_path, target_size=(120, 160))
# convert PIL.Image.Image type to 3D tensor with shape (120, 160, 3)
x = image.img_to_array(img)
```

---

***Update***:
It seems the reason you had to make all images squared (128,128,1) is that in model.fit(), training examples (x_train) and labels (normally y_train) are the same set. If you look at the model summary below, after the Flatten layer everything becomes a square. It is therefore expecting labels to be squares. It makes sense: using this model for prediction would transform a (120,160,1) image into something of the shape (128, 128, 1). Changing model training to below code should therefore work:

```
x_train = random.random((90, 5, 120, 160, 1)) # training data
y_train = random.random((90, 5, 128, 128, 1)) # labels
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 5, 120, 160, 64)   320       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 5, 60, 80, 64)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_3 (TimeDist (None, 5, 60, 80, 32)     18464     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDist (None, 5, 30, 40, 32)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_5 (TimeDist (None, 5, 30, 40, 16)     4624      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_6 (TimeDist (None, 5, 15, 20, 16)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_7 (TimeDist (None, 5, 4800)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 64)             1245440   
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_8 (TimeDist (None, 5, 8, 8, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_9 (TimeDist (None, 5, 16, 16, 1)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_10 (TimeDis (None, 5, 16, 16, 16)     160       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_11 (TimeDis (None, 5, 32, 32, 16)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_12 (TimeDis (None, 5, 32, 32, 32)     4640      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_13 (TimeDis (None, 5, 64, 64, 32)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_14 (TimeDis (None, 5, 64, 64, 64)     18496     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_15 (TimeDis (None, 5, 128, 128, 64)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_16 (TimeDis (None, 5, 128, 128, 1)    577       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,292,721
Trainable params: 1,292,721
Non-trainable params: 0
```

***Update 2***:
To make it work with non-square images without changing y, set LSTM(300), Reshape(15, 20, 1), and you remove one of the Conv2D + Upsampling layers afterwards. Then you can use pictures with shape (120,160) even in an autoencoder. The trick is to look at the model summary, and make sure after the LSTM you start with the right shape so that after adding all the other layers, the end result is a shape of (120,160).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(
    TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation="relu", padding="same"), =(5, 120, 160, 1)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(units=300, return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Reshape((15, 20, 1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same')))


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.summary()

x_train = random.random((90, 5, 120, 160, 1))
y_train = random.random((90, 5, 120, 160, 1))

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: i think it may also work if you specify input_shape=(75, 120, 160, 1), ignoring any rgb channels.

Comment: exactly, you would have to apply this at the point where you have the individual video frame as an image. You would then process it with above code, and store the resulting 'x' in your training array for the Keras model, now with shape (120, 160, 3), per image.

Comment: the code runs super slow now. actually earlier during preprocessing i had converted each frame to grayscale and the appended each frame to a list, then appended that list to another list(frame->frame_list->video_list) and converted it to an array. How different is PIL from this?

Comment: i tried with (75,120,160,1) and it returns ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_548 to have shape (75, 128, 128, 1) but got array with shape (75, 120, 160, 1)

Comment: i tried the change you said with PIL and now my array is (100,75,120,160,1) with each frame as a grayscale. do i need to try with rgb frame. the above error came with this new data

Comment: ok that makes sense, as if they are already grayscale, img_to_array would only have one channel - thought they were color. Ok, so looking at the error you get: did you anywhere in your code chose a shape of (128, 128) for your array? It seems to expect the images to be in that format.

Comment: no i didnt.. i dont know if the model reshapes it to 128x128. also the dataset is already in 120x160 size

Comment: could you provide a sample x_train array, so i could run it, maybe with a few entries?

Comment: never mind, this `x_train = random.random((10, 75, 120, 160, 1))` seems to work

Comment: sorry, my system just crashed, i resized each image to 128x128 changed input_shape as per the error. got output till Epoch(1/100) and system crashed...ill reduce frame count and try again with a single video and will update soon..btw..is that 10 the batch_size?

Comment: thats the 99 in your case, so number of videos i think

Comment: im using 2 videos taking 5 frames from each and training now. its working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr.Kai Aeberli for his assistance. I was able to run the model after resizing the image to 128x128 dimension.The size of dataset may cause system to crash in absence of gpu. Reduce size as necessary. Please refer to the whole comment section if you have doubts. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/sh1j1th/cnn-lstm) in github

Comment: that's great to hear! Would you be able to post the full working code? Maybe with some random sample data like `x_train = random.random((10, 75, 128, 128, 1))` and ideally all the correct imports at the top.

Comment: Oh yes..ill upload the frame extraction code and lstm-cnn code once i properly comment it. ill upload the numpy files as well.

Comment: updated the answer with reason for square image issue

Comment: @KaiAeberli I saw your update on reshaping but since this is an autoencoder and mine doesnt have any `y_train` where should i put it? also i tried training the model but at first the training loss and validation loss is low and at the same range but on subsequent training they seem to deviate and validation loss tends to be higher than training loss. There are spikes in mse plot

Comment: yes you're right - with autoencoders square image are a bit tricky, as the convolutional layers square everything once it has been flattened. It might work to add a Reshape() layer at the end or just after the LSTM() layer.

Comment: true: i had a look: if you set LSTM(300),  Reshape(15, 20, 1), and you remove one of the Conv2D + Upsampling layers afterwards, you can use pictures with shape (120,160) even in an autoencoder. The trick is to look at the model summary, and make sure after the LSTM you start with the right shape so that after adding all the other layers, the end result is a shape of (120,160). Updated the answer.